# Develop for Microsoft Office 2013 using Microsoft Office 2016

Tags: office-interop, multiple-versions

Is it possible to install assemblies or tools for Microsoft Office 2013 on development machine that has Microsoft Office 2016?

Or for example can i target/develop for multiple versions of Microsoft Office on a development PC that has Microsoft Office 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can support lower Office versions out of the box. Solutions that were created by using Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2010 can run in Office 2013, Office 2010, or the 2007 Microsoft Office system. However, the solution can use only those features and APIs that are available in all three versions of Office. See [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) for more information.